# Hadoop: execute local method bewteen 2 jobs

Tags: function, methods, hadoop, mapreduce, local

Is there a way to execute a (relatively short) local method on the data between two subsequent MapReduce jobs?

If yes, how to accomplish it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

One easy way to do that is:

1. Declare your job objects `Job job1 = new Job(conf1);` and `Job job2 = new Job(conf2);`
2. Set the correct mapper/reducer and job name for these jobs.
3. In the Main function,  you can do something like this:

   ```
   job1.waitForCompletion(true);
   //execute your local method
   method();
   job2.waitForCompletion(true);
   ```

Comment: Thank you! Is there also a way to hand over the values from job1 to the local method? Or do I have to read in the values from job1 with a StreamReader?

Comment: What kind of values are you talking about? MapReduce jobs typically write output to HDFS and don't return any values.

Comment: I'm talking about the values of the (key,value)-pairs written to HDFS. My values are ArrayLists and I want to hand them over to the local method.

Comment: You'll have to read the <key,value> pairs from the output directory of the first job

Comment: Can I store the ArrayList as such and not as Strings, so that I'm able to read them in as ArrayLists again? By the way I really appreciate your help. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure of that, but as far as my understanding goes, I don't think that's possible.

Comment: @fr3qu3nzy: Try SequenceOutputFormat to store binary. May be serialize you ArrayList too. :)